# how to know the intensity value of every pixel in accordig to C,M,Y in matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose, I have a color image; I want to know every pixel's intensity value for three specified color as R,G,B as three different matrix value or C,M,Y value as three different matrix. then I will convert that intensity value as binary; I ant to do it on Matlab. How can i get these values?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Loading the image into MATLAB? Converting RGB->CMY? Converting `uint8` to `logical`? What do you mean by "these values"?

Comment: i want to do two process here; firstly, I want to know the intensity values of every pixel of that color image; as we know that, all colors are combination of R,G,B. so that I want 3 different matrix for 3 different r,g,b color intensity. (C,M,Y is just of like getting R,G,B matrix,this is optional). and secondly i want to convert every matrix values into binary; thiS way the intensity of the image will be converted into binary; could I clear about it to you?

Comment: When you load a color image into MATLAB, you get a 3d array. Splitting those to 3 different arrays is trivial (`im = imread('path\to\img.jpg'); R = im(:,:,1);` etc.). Converting to binary is also quite simple: `R(R < 128) = 0; R = ~~R;`. So where's the problem? What did you try?